# Why does this RegExp query return all results?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB 3.2 server. My collection contains documents like the following:

```
{
    "name": "string",
    "explicitMods": [
        "+48 to Blah",
        "-13% to Blah",
        "12 to 18 to Blah"
    ]
}
```

If I write this:

> myCollection.find({ "explicitMods": /bad string/ })

I get zero results, as expected.

However if I write this:

> myCollection.find({ "explicitMods": /\d+ to \d+/ })

I get all documents in the collection. This is unexpected because I actually want documents containing substrings like `12 to 18`. If I change the regexp to `/\d+ to \d+z/` it correctly matches nothing.

Comment: Can you update your question to provide an example document that the query is returning, but that you don't want included?

Comment: Your query seems to work. So are you trying to filter `explicitMods` in that one document?

Comment: Perhaps you need to anchor your regexp with either `^` at the beginning or `$` at the end of the expression, if you don't want any other characters preceding or following your "12 to 18" - in other words, an expression such as `/^\d+ to \d+$/`. That might help?

Comment: Building a PoE indexer? :)

Answer (score 1):

The query you are issuing **"correctly"** returns the **documents** that actually match the condition you ask it to. That being that "at least one" array element in the property you are testing actually matches the condition in the query.

From this we can surmise two possible outcomes:

1. Your intent is to only return the documents where **all** array entries satisfy the condition.
2. Your intent is to "filter" the entries from the "array within the document" only returning those results which satisfy the condition.

From these there are varying approaches. Firstly being that there is in fact no such query operator for MongoDB which demands that "all" array elements must be satisfied by the given condition with a "regular query". Therefore, you need to apply logic in a different form.

One such option is to use the JavaScript evaluation of [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) in a manner that inspects the array content. Here you can apply [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in order to test your condition, in addition to the regular query filter of course since that actually is doing some useful work.

Given source documents like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993a35be38f41729f1d6501"),
    "name" : "string",
    "explicitMods" : [ 
        "+48 to Blah", 
        "-13% to Blah", 
        "12 to 18 to Blah"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993a35be38f41729f1d6502"),
    "name" : "string",
    "explicitMods" : [ 
        "12 to 18 to Blah"
    ]
}
```

Where your intention is only to return the "document" which matches "all" array elements, you issue the statement:

```
db.myCollection.find({ 
  "explicitMods": /\d+ to \d+/,
  "$where": function() { return this.explicitMods.every(e => /\d+ to \d+/.test(e)) }
  }
})
```

Which returns only the matching document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993a35be38f41729f1d6502"),
    "name" : "string",
    "explicitMods" : [ 
        "12 to 18 to Blah"
    ]
}
```

In the alternate case to using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), the aggregation framework of MongoDB allows expressions using "native coded operators" which generally apply faster than JavaScript interpreted expressions. However there actually is no such "logical operator" equivalent ( See [SERVER-11947](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) ) of [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) that is applicable to aggregation operations such as [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/).

Therefore the only approach available here is to instead use [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with regular query conditions "after" the array elements have been denormalized using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  // Match "possible" documents
  { "$match": { "explicitMods": /\d+ to \d+/ } },

  // unwind to denormalize
  { "$unwind": "$explicitMods" },

  // Match on the "array" items now as documents
  { "$match": { "explicitMods": /\d+ to \d+/ } },

  // Optionally "re-group" back to documents with only matching array items
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "explicitMods": { "$push": "$explicitMods" }
  }}
])
```

And that one will return "both" documents, but only those with matching array items:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993a35be38f41729f1d6501"),
    "name" : "string",
    "explicitMods" : [ 
        "12 to 18 to Blah"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993a35be38f41729f1d6502"),
    "name" : "string",
    "explicitMods" : [ 
        "12 to 18 to Blah"
    ]
}
```

Of course you can apply a "variation" on that theme and "test the length" of the array against the filter condition in order to decide which document to return:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "explicitMods": /\d+ to \d+/ } },
  { "$addFields": { "origSize": { "$size": "$explicitMods" } } },
  { "$unwind": "$explicitMods" },
  { "$match": { "explicitMods": /\d+ to \d+/ } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "origSize": { "$first": "$origSize" },
    "explicitMods": { "$push": "$explicitMods" },
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { 
        "$eq": [
          { "$size": "$explicitMods" },
          "$origSize"
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

But whilst it does the same thing as the original option with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) using "native operators", the general cost of such operations as [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) makes it's utility questionable, and therefore likely to take considerably more time and resources to produce the result than the original query.